# Magento, layout not looking the same on all the pages

Tags: php, templates, magento, layout

*Some of the things I have done to try and fix it* : 
 - I have tried changing from 3columns.phtml to the one I worked on - 2columns-left.phtml, on many different places but it already says 2columns~. 
 - Tried clearing cache lots of times.
 - Also changed to this template in cms and category as well but still isn't
   working.

**My first page is doing what I want it to do. But when I click on products or any cms-page, then the logo and header looks completely wack and is even missing a background element that I added with div in the header.phtml**

Does anyone have a clue of why this happens? :( And where I'm supposed to change something?

*From the 2columns-left.phtml* :

```
<?php
/**
 * Template for Mage_Page_Block_Html
 */
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>">
<head>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('head') ?>
</head>
<body<?php echo $this->getBodyClass()?' class="'.$this->getBodyClass().'"':'' ?>>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after_body_start') ?>
<div class="wrapper">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_notices') ?>
    <div class="page">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>
        <div class="main-container col2-left-layout">
            <div class="main">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
                <div class="col-main">
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-left sidebar"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left') ?></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('before_body_end') ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getAbsoluteFooter() ?>
</body>
</html>
```

*From the header.phtml* :

```
<?php
/**

/**
 * @var Mage_Page_Block_Html_Header $this
 */
?>
<div class="header-container">
    <div class="header">
        <?php if ($this->getIsHomePage()):?>
                <div class="header-menu">
        <p></p>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>
        </div>
        <div class="header-bg">
        <h1 class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a></h1>
        <?php else:?>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a>
        <?php endif?>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="quick-access">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('store_language') ?>
        <p class="welcome-msg"><?php echo $this->getWelcome()?></p>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks') ?>
    </div>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topBar') ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topContainer'); ?>
</div>
```

*This works on the first page (the index/home), but then on all the other pages when I click around - the header doesn't seem to include this code (atleast that's what I think because it doesn't look like it does)* :

```
            <div class="header-menu">
    <p></p>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>
    </div>
    <div class="header-bg">
    <h1 class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a></h1>
    <?php else:?>
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a>
    <?php endif?>
    </div>
```

Comment: Could you post the code in `2columns-left.phtml`?

Comment: updated my question now for you, so it has more information :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your code outside of the getIsHomePage()):?> check

```
<?php
/**

/**
 * @var Mage_Page_Block_Html_Header $this
 */
?>
<div class="header-container">
    <div class="header">
        <?php if ($this->getIsHomePage()):?>
                <div class="header-menu">
        <p></p>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>
        </div>
        <div class="header-bg">
        <h1 class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a></h1>
        <?php else:?>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a>
        <?php endif?>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="quick-access">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('store_language') ?>
        <p class="welcome-msg"><?php echo $this->getWelcome()?></p>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks') ?>
    </div>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topBar') ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topContainer'); ?>
</div>
```

should become something like:

```
<?php
/**

/**
 * @var Mage_Page_Block_Html_Header $this
 */
?>
<div class="header-container">
    <div class="header">

        <div class="header-menu">
        <p></p>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>
        </div>
        <div class="header-bg">
         <?php if ($this->getIsHomePage()):?>
        <h1 class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a></h1>
        <?php else:?>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a>
        <?php endif?>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="quick-access">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('store_language') ?>
        <p class="welcome-msg"><?php echo $this->getWelcome()?></p>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks') ?>
    </div>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topBar') ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topContainer'); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: This helped instantly, thank you sooooooo much!

Answer (score 1):

The test `<?php if ($this->getIsHomePage()):?>`, which is checking if the homepage is active, is misplaced and therefore wraps too much code : when the current page is not the homepage, some tags aren't closed, and the menu or the header background aren't displayed.

Usually, this rather looks like this :

```
<?php if ($this->getIsHomePage()):?>
<h1 class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a></h1>
<?php else:?>
<a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a>
<?php endif?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help :) It was this problem that you and the person below said.